# How can i extract a specific field of a compund datatype as an array

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

I have a HDF5 file containing (among other elements) an array of compound data, like for example:

```
    DATASET "AgentDataSet" {
        DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
           H5T_STD_I32LE "LifeState";
           H5T_STD_I32LE "CellIdx";
           H5T_STD_I32LE "CellID";
           H5T_STD_I64LE "AgentID";
           H5T_IEEE_F32LE "BirthTime";
           H5T_STD_U8LE "Gender";
           H5T_IEEE_F32LE "Age";
           H5T_IEEE_F32LE "LastBirth";
        }
        DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 2252984 ) / ( 2252984 ) }
}
```

The members of the compound data may differ between files, but i know that `LifeState`, `CellIdx`, `CellID`, and `AgentID` are always contained in the compound data type (even at the same locations).

My application does not know the precise structure of the compound data and so can not define an appropriate `struct` to be used in `H5Tread()`.

Is there a way to extract the fields `AgentID` and `CellID` from the  array of compound data into an array of

```
struct {
  int iAgendID;
  int iCellID;   
}
```

i.e. ignoring the rest of the fields?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it:
I define this struct:

```
struct info_t {
    idtype   m_ulID;
    gridtype m_ulCellID;
};
```

Then i create a corresponding HDF5 data type:

```
    hid_t hInfoDataType = H5Tcreate (H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof (info_t));

    info_t ii;
    H5Tinsert(hInfoDataType, SPOP_DT_CELL_ID,  HOFFSET(info_t, m_ulCellID), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    H5Tinsert(hInfoDataType, SPOP_DT_AGENT_ID, HOFFSET(info_t, m_ulID),     INT_NATIVE_LONG);
```

Then, assuming the appropriate dataspace (`hDataSpace`) has been opened, i read and use the data:

```
    hsize_t dims;
    H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(hDataSpace, &dims, NULL);
    info_t *pInfos = new info_t[dims];

    hid_t hMemSpace = H5Screate_simple (1, &dims, NULL); 
    herr_t status = H5Dread(hDataSet, hAgentDataType, hMemSpace, hDataSpace, H5P_DEFAULT, pInfos);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d; a %ld, c %d\n", i, pInfos[i].m_ulID, pInfos[i].m_ulCellID);
    }
    delete[] pInfos;
```